# How to create .d.ts file in the Vue Js 3 + Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

working with Vue js 3 and Laravel 8 project. in the project installed via npm vue editor js package as following. https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/vue-editor-js and I have following app.js file app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import router from './router'
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import mainapp from './components/mainapp.vue';
import common from './common'
import store from './store'
import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index'


createApp({
    components: {
        mainapp,
        
        },
    
}).use(router).use(store).use(ViewUIPlus).use(Editor).mixin(common).mount('#app');
```

import file import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index' generated following error message

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-editor-js/src/index'. 'F:/2021 Technics/vue + laravel/vue 3/fullstack/node_modules/vue-editor-js/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/vue-editor-js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-editor-js/src/index';
```

after referring documentation and other resources to fix this problem need to create

```
create a file named vue-editor-js.d.ts containing the line: declare module 'vue-editor-js/src/index
```

how could I do this to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you created the vue-editor-js.d.ts file ?

Comment: @Vins yes in the laravel project (inside the main file) but my vue-editor.js file in the node_module. what is the correct path unable to identify what is the root

Comment: why are you importing the index file from source code of an npm package- `import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index'`

Comment: @RHNCHN because i am using laravel + Vue js project so I need import Editor to the app.js